# PHP only getting the last value of the loop

Tags: javascript, php, json

Im only getting the last value of my `foreach loop` and i gave it a unique id for all and i still get the last value

```
   <?php
        if (!empty($array)){
            foreach($array['users'] as $id){
                echo '<a href="#" id="btnClick" onClick="clickEvent();">
                        <div class="choices">
                            <dl>
                                <dt id="id'.$id['userID'].'">'.$id['userID'] .'</dt>
                                <dd id="name">'.$id['userName'].'</dd>    
                                <dd>'.$key.'</dd>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                      </a>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

and here is my `javascript` that i use to get the id so i can put it on url directly.

```
function clickEvent(){
        var foo = "<?php echo $id['userID'] ?>";
        var json = 'http://batz.web/Sandbox/details.php?userID=' + foo1;
        console.log(json);
        $.getJSON(json, function (results){
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = results.users[0].userID;
            document.getElementById("body").innerText = results.users[0].userAddress;
        });
    }
```

Comment: So what do you expect - you output the last value in your `<?php echo $id['userID'] ?>`.

Comment: @u_mulder -- i expect that every item in the loop have different ones as the loop goes.

Comment: It does not connected to a loop. The problem is that after the loop is over - the `$id` stores the last value of a loop. And this __last__ `$id` is used in your `clickEvent()` function.

Comment: You're over writing the variables each time through the loop. You need to figure out a way (like concatenation) to preserve each loop, then echo.

Comment: @u_mulder - Oh, okay. Is there any method that can do what I want to achieve?

Comment: side note - you have a few non unique `id`s in your loops -> `id="btnClick"` & `id="name"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your loop is over, the value of `$id` holds the **last** value of a loop. So, this last value is output in

```
var foo = "<?php echo $id['userID'] ?>";
```

One of the solutions can be passing `$id['userID']` as a parameter to `clickEvent`:

```
echo '<a href="#" id="btnClick" onClick="clickEvent(' . $id['userID'] . ');">
```

And define `clickEvent` as:

```
// now foo is an argument
function clickEvent(foo){
    var json = 'http://batz.web/Sandbox/details.php?userID=' + foo;  // use foo, not foo1
    console.log(json);
    $.getJSON(json, function (results){
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = results.users[0].userID;
        document.getElementById("body").innerText = results.users[0].userAddress;
    });
}
```

Comment: `foo` != `foo1`

Comment: @Sean correct, I'll fix this, though it is in OP's code already)

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = "<?php echo $id['userID'] ?>";
```

The value of `$id` is the last element in `$array['users']` as `foreach` loops over it. Hence, `$id['serID']` is the last element's `userId`.

One easy solution is modify `clickEvent()` to accept a parameter, `userId` in this case.

PHP:

```
echo '<a href="#" id="btnClick" onClick="clickEvent("' . $id['userID'] . '");">
      ......';
```

And the JavaScipt would be:

```
function clickEvent(userId){
        var json = 'http://batz.web/Sandbox/details.php?userID=' + userId;
        console.log(json);
        $.getJSON(json, function (results){
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = results.users[0].userID;
            document.getElementById("body").innerText = results.users[0].userAddress;
        });
    }
```